# CosmosSDK Java 4.52.0 changeFeedBuilder no longer supports ChangeFeedObserver, how to get the "fetch" ChangeRequest?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

In the older SDK version when creating a ChangeFeedProcessor a ChangeFeedObserver implementation should be provided.
The ChangeFeedObserver contained the ChangeFeedObserverContext which contains the FeedResponse which contains the requestCharge.

Is there a way to get the requestCharge somehow using the new Publisher based ChangeFeedProcessor initializer?

EDIT:
Previous code (SDK 4.37.1):

```
return new ChangeFeedProcessorBuilderImpl()
    .options(cfOptions)
    .hostName(host)
    .feedContainer(feedInputContainer)
    .leaseContainer(leaseContainer)
    .observerFactory(() -> new CosmosStatisticsChangeFeedObserver(cosmosEventsProcessor, metrics))
    .build();
```

Where "CosmosStatisticsChangeFeedObserver" is an implementation of ChangeFeedObserver{JsonNode}

New implementation (SDK 4.52.0):

```
return new ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder()
    .options(cfOptions)
    .hostName(host)
    .feedContainer(feedInputContainer)
    .leaseContainer(leaseContainer)
    .handleLatestVersionChanges(new CosmosChangeFeedChangeHandler(metrics, cosmosEventsProcessor))
    .buildChangeFeedProcessor();
```

Where "CosmosChangeFeedChangeHandler" is an implementation of "Consumer{List{ChangeFeedProcessorItem}}". (Can't display "<"s)

In the new Consumer based changefeedhandler the "feedResponse" is missing, thus I cannot get the RequestCharge upon receiving feed items. Only "ChangeFeedProcessorItem" is present which doesnt contain RU info.

Comment: Can you share a code snippet to show what you mean? What was the previous Java SDK version you were using before 4.52.0?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta updated the original post, thanks for responding. Also "deprecating CFO" might be improper wording, as it's technically not deprecated, but the SDK changefeedbuilder no longer supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems its not available, created a feature request in Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/37461

Answer (score 1):

Seems `ChangeFeedProcessorBuilderImpl` is not the public surface area but rather the internal implementation.

Using `xxxxxImpl` is not something that I see any example or documentation referring to and seems that being internal, there is no contract violation if these are changed, as they are internal implementations of the public surface APIs.

If your requirement is to obtain the RU Charge, I would post this requirement on the Java SDK repository: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues so the team can track this requirement and make sure it is addressed.

EDIT: One alternative is to hook into the Metrics/Diagnostics as https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/2c2283f9658b77af4cfccca2c6985f85f0781509/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos-tests/src/test/java/com/azure/cosmos/CosmosDiagnosticsE2ETest.java#L137-L148 shows:

```
CosmosClientBuilder builder = this
            .getClientBuilder()
            .clientTelemetryConfig(
                new CosmosClientTelemetryConfig()
                    .diagnosticsThresholds(
                        new CosmosDiagnosticsThresholds()
                            .setPointOperationLatencyThreshold(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                            .setNonPointOperationLatencyThreshold(Duration.ofMillis(2000))
                            .setRequestChargeThreshold(100)
                    )
                    .diagnosticsHandler(CosmosDiagnosticsHandler.DEFAULT_LOGGING_HANDLER)
            );
```

Comment: Matias Quaranta It's interesting you mention it's not a user facing interface, I based my implementation on this documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.cosmos.changefeedprocessor?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: But that linked document does not mention anything about `ChangeFeedProcessorBuilderImpl`. It is all `ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder`. Maybe in an old version the documentation was wrong and it was pointing to `ChangeFeedProcessorBuilderImpl`?

Comment: Thats true (to be honest since I updated the ChangeFeed to "ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder" - I just didn't notice the difference), the question still stands though. In the example mentioned in the docs, the publisher does not return anything that contains the RequestUsage for fetching a set of docs, only the docs themselves.

Comment: Agree. There is no public API at the moment to do that. If this is what you require, please file the Issue on the linked repository as a feature request to help the team guide the effort.

Comment: Sure will do, mark the question as resolved, thanks for your help

Comment: Feature request created https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/37461 for anyone interested.